# Как переключить фокус между элементами формы

Tags: c++builder

В с++ builder-e создал калькулятор.

В самом "form" у меня два edit-a, и нужно сделать так (в коде), чтобы, нажав "Enter", переключиться с одного Edit-a на другой, и дальше ввести данные (имею ввиду цифры).

Comment: Для переключения на другое поле используй фокус, что-то типа  Edit->SetFocus();